# How to set xfce4-screenshooter by default to save screenshots as jpg not png?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, screenshot

xfce screenshooter normally saves screenshots as png files and modifying its extension for every file I want to save is an arduous work (considering the many screenshots I take on a daily basis).

I couldn't find any integrated option for xfce-screenshooter for this purpose. How can I change to default extension of the screenshots saved to jpg instead of png?

Comment: In the file `$HOME/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter` change the line `last_extension=png` to `last_extension=jpg`. This worked well enough on my system...

Comment: Unfortunately there was no option such as "last_extension=png". Tried adding that statement but didn't work.

Comment: That is odd. My full config file is here: https://pastebin.com/86GL2p4i Can you post yours as well?

Comment: pastebin.com/ktGBtGdj    #PeppermintOS 10

Comment: We may have different versions perhaps: `xfce4-screenshooter --version` on my system shows: xfce4-screenshooter 1.9.10

Comment: Mine is xfce4-screenshooter 1.9.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135727/discussion-between-andrew-46-and-user668687).